# jquery trigger does not work in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, triggers

I'm trying to load a modal window with a link like http://www.domain.com/?prod=lorem-ipsum-3
but it doesn't load in Chrome, Safari or IE. Opera and FF works fine.

Modal window is called as iframe. Other buttons which supposed to open modal window also works fine in all browsers.

P.S. You can see all the code in given site.

Comment: The Opera browser has also got a javascript console. Have you checked her for any errors?

Comment: It looks like it works fine on Chrome.

Comment: Please post relevant code here. With only an external link the question becomes worthless to future generations once the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a race condition in your code - the `ModalManager` initializes the click handler during the `DOMContentReady` event and your code to click the link runs in the handler for the same event (via `jQuery(document).ready()`). Which one gets to run first is undefined, you could just as well consider it as random. So there is always the possibility that your code triggers a click on the hidden link but the handler for it isn't set up yet. To prevent the race condition you could either run your code immediately *after* `DOMContentReady` (easiest way to do this would be putting `setTimeout(..., 0)` into the event handler) or attach your event handler to the window's `load` event instead.